# How to organize Python code into collapsable / expandable chunks?

Tags: python, pycharm

In Pycharm, there's "code structurure" side bar which provides a tree to navigate through the code, but, it is only useful when the code has classes and methods and objects. If nothing of that is in code then it is  useless.
My question is: is there any way in which I dictate that this is a block, and I want to be able to collapse it and expand it? Something similar to Jupyter where the code is inherently divided to cells.

Currently, I'm doing this:

```
# ---------------------------------- chunck x blah blah -----------------------
```

EDIT: 
Most of comments say that I'm dumb and I don't know how to code efficiently and that I should use functions and classes. Guys, I know how to use those, that's not my question. Thanks.

Comment: I'm using them wherever possible. I just can't use them everywhere especially when processing data that requires 's 10's of inputs and returns 10's of outputs.

Comment: That seems odd, but if you have a large number of parameters being passed around you can always use a dictionary, a named tuple, or even create a class. You need functions.

Comment: IMO, you should simply start learning to write code in an organized manner, which would involve functions and classes, etc. Having a bunch of business logic running in the global scope is bad. In any case, what is wrong with your comment approach? That seems like exactly the solution you are looking for (although, not the solution you probably need)

Comment: @KirkBroadhurst, is this a standard practice?  Making blocks of code a function so that they can be called, and to organize.

Comment: Say that some task is required for one time, and is doeable in 3 nested for loops, I don't see why I need a function. It will waste my time and clutter the code. I'm sure that I don't have problem with creating them when need arise.

Comment: Does Pycharm also offer block collapsing for `if` statements?  If so, you can use `if True:` as a cheap way to denote blocks.

Comment: If adding functions delivers your desired ability to collapse code I don't see how it creates clutter.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga I should have made it clear in my question that I'm not a bigginer. I know how to use classes and functions professionally. This is not my problem. The processing that I'm doing requires so many steps, so I want to have it dividable to pieces.

Comment: @AlexDeft *that's what functions are for*. If you don't want to use functions, and you don't want to use the comment solution you have, what exactly are you looking for?

Comment: @ColinMac yes, it is standard practice, although maybe sometimes you can get away with a simple two or three line script, but even then many organizations will require your scripts to be properly modularized (i.e. wrapped in functions/classes, for example, at my workplace, we make all our scripts using the `click` library). in the end this makes things better for everyone. the people writing the code, the people reading the code ...

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga functions are used for repetitive tasks. I don't waste my time creating a function and use it once. I can just have the body of the function outisde. and that's it.

Comment: @JohnGordon This is a pretty neat and elegant solution

Comment: @AlexDeft That's not the only point of functions, although it's certainly a good reason to create a function. They can also be used to express intent, it gives a meaningful name to a block of code. This is better than a comment at the beginning of the block.

Comment: The fact that you want to be able to collapse that block strongly suggest that it should be given a name. When you collapse it you'll still see the name.

Comment: @Barmar I see your point. Functions are good candidate solutions. But, still, I hate passing dozens of parameters to it. and returning another dozen.

Comment: How big a block are we talking about? Dozens of parameters and return values sounds excessive for any block of code that's a meaningful unit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PyCharm allows you to define 'code cells' when you have 'Scientific Mode' enabled. These code cells are collapsible and expandable. To quote from the [PyCharm website](https://blog.jetbrains.com/pycharm/2018/02/pycharm-2018-1-eap-4/):

> A “code cell” is a block of lines to be executed all at once in the
>   integrated Python console. You can define cells simply by adding
>   inline comments #%% to your regular Python files. PyCharm detects
>   these comments and shows you a special run icon in the left gutter.
>   Clicking this icon triggers the execution of a cell:
>
> [image]

The only catch is that Scientific Mode and its code cell functionality are only available in PyCharm Professional Edition.

Comment: Woah! This is amazing! I thought this was only available when you use Pycharm to open Jupyter files.

Comment: May I know what code coloring style is used in that screenshot?

Comment: @AlexDeft I'm reasonably certain it's the *monokai* color scheme.

Comment: This is working only with the premium version, as far as I know.

Comment: @Gildas Correct. This is and has always been clearly stated *in the answer* itself.

Answer (score 6):

You can select a region, and press ctr+alt+t, then select <editor-fold...>. This will surround the region with a comment that makes the region collapsible. You can also do this manually by adding the following around the region:

```
# <editor-fold desc="This text is shown when collapsed">

# </editor-fold>
```

Comment: NICE. This is what I was looking for: a clean folding, like the one for the imports

Comment: The same effect can be achieved without the comments around the code by selecting an area and pressing ctrl + .

Answer (score 4):

Turns out that the answer is very simple:
Select the code, right click, do custom folding

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I sometimes use `True` conditional statements to create collapsible blocks in PyCharm and other IDEs. This also helps me to visually relate all indented code, access it when needed, and collapse it, when I'm focusing on other parts of my code.

```
if True:
   # block code goes here
```

A fancier way is to use a descriptive string in the condition. The description stays visible for a collapsed block. You can also disable these with negation anytime, if needed.

```
if 'Define similarities':
    Dot = lambda x, y: x @ y
    CosSim = lambda x, y: x @ y / (x @ x)**0.5 / (y @ y)**0.5
```