# Creating block of codes in Python

Tags: r, python-3.x

In `R`, I can create a collapsible block of codes using

```
{
## My R code
}
```

I am wondering if there is any similar approach for `Python`? Clearly above `{}` is not working in `Python`. I tried with `:`, but still get error.

Any pointer will be very helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Or you can use a dummy "if True:" like in:

```
if True:
   #now you are in a new block of code
   #
```

Answer (score 1):

No, there is no similar approach in Python. You can make use of methods or classes, which are close to collapsible block of codes, eg.:

```py
def foo():
    # do something

if __name__ == "__main__":
    foo()
```

Nevertheless there is no possibility to create such code blocks in a simple script without using methods or classes.

The only thing, which comes close to collapsible block of codes is the `code cell` feature from PyCharm. Find more informations about this [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56997402/16047487).

Comment: Okay. That is one of the things why I hate `Python`, I would rather call `Python` functions from `R` using `reticulate` package

Answer (score 0):

Technically you can use brackets

```
def function():
    {
        print("Witam")
    }

function()
```

And python interpreter can read this, but i would say it's not recomended and doesn't go along with pythonic way of working with code:D